# ExtJS Form UI get disrupt due to error message on field below

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

I am beginner to sencha architect and in ExtJS. When I placed error message in below textfield, this textfield moved little up because of `vertical-align: middle` has been assigned by sencha architect. How to fix that issue.

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/guides/components/forms.html

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
renderTo: document.body,
title: 'User Form',
height: 350,
width: 300,
bodyPadding: 10,
defaultType: 'textfield',
items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        flex: 1,
        cls: [
            'customInput',
            'formTextBlack'
        ],
        minHeight: 55,
        fieldLabel: 'Pack Type',
        labelAlign: 'top',
        labelCls: 'blackLabelText14',
        labelSeparator: ' ',
        msgTarget: 'under',
        name: 'packType',
        fieldStyle: 'background:transparent',
        readOnly: false,
        allowBlank: false,
        allowOnlyWhitespace: false
    },
    {
        fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
        name: 'lastName'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'datefield',
        fieldLabel: 'Date of Birth',
        name: 'birthDate'
    }
]
});
```

Comment: Do you mean the label vertical align? if so, probably it's about the "labelCls" attribute that replace the default one (which has the middle align)

Comment: no i mean when error comes input field moves little up to adjust error message while it should remain on its place and error should increase the height of component

Answer (score 1):

For this there is two way

- Using `height` and `scrollable:'y'` or `scrollable:true` of [`form`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.form.Panel.html) component. In this case scroll-able height of form will automatically increase/decrease when `error` message show/hide respectively. Please refer this working **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2c7t)** for this way.
- Without `height` and `scrollable` of [`form`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.form.Panel.html)
  component. In this case height of form will
  automatically increase/decrease when `error` message show/hide
  respectively. Please refer this working
  **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2c7u)** for this way.

I hope this will help you or guide you to achieve your requirement.

> **Code Snippet with height and scroll-able config**

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: document.body,
    title: 'User Form',
    height: 350,
    scrollable: 'y',//true
    width: '100%',
    bodyPadding: 10,
    defaults: {
        flex: 1,
        anchor: '100%',
        labelSeparator: '',
        margin: '10 20',
        minHeight: 55,
        xtype: 'textfield',
        labelAlign: 'top',
        allowBlank: false,
        msgTarget: 'under' // location of the error message
    },
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'Last Login Time',
        name: 'loginTime',
        regex: /^([1-9]|1[0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(\s[a|p]m)$/i,
        maskRe: /[\d\s:amp]/i,
        invalidText: 'Not a valid time.  Must be in the format "12:34 PM".'
    }, {
        fieldLabel: 'First Name',
        name: 'firstName'
    }, {
        fieldLabel: 'Middle Name',
        allowBlank: true,
        name: 'firstName'
    }, {
        fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
        name: 'lastName'
    }, {
        fieldLabel: 'Email',
        name: 'email'
    }, {
        xtype: 'datefield',
        fieldLabel: 'Date of Join',
        name: 'joinDate',
        invalidText: '"{0}" not valid.enter value should be like  "{1}" .' // custom error message text
    }, {
        xtype: 'datefield',
        fieldLabel: 'Date of Birth',
        name: 'birthDate',
        invalidText: '"{0}" bad. "{1}" good.' // custom error message text
    }]
});
```

> **Code Snippet without height and without scroll-able config**

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: document.body,
    title: 'User Form',
    width: '100%',
    bodyPadding: 10,
    defaults: {
        flex: 1,
        anchor: '100%',
        labelSeparator: '',
        margin: '10 20',
        minHeight: 55,
        xtype: 'textfield',
        labelAlign: 'top',
        allowBlank: false,
        msgTarget: 'under' // location of the error message
    },
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'Last Login Time',
        name: 'loginTime',
        regex: /^([1-9]|1[0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(\s[a|p]m)$/i,
        maskRe: /[\d\s:amp]/i,
        invalidText: 'Not a valid time.  Must be in the format "12:34 PM".'
    }, {
        fieldLabel: 'First Name',
        name: 'firstName'
    }, {
        fieldLabel: 'Middle Name',
        allowBlank: true,
        name: 'firstName'
    }, {
        fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
        name: 'lastName'
    }, {
        fieldLabel: 'Email',
        name: 'email'
    }, {
        xtype: 'datefield',
        fieldLabel: 'Date of Join',
        name: 'joinDate',
        invalidText: '"{0}" not valid.enter value should be like  "{1}" .' // custom error message text
    }, {
        xtype: 'datefield',
        fieldLabel: 'Date of Birth',
        name: 'birthDate',
        invalidText: '"{0}" bad. "{1}" good.' // custom error message text
    }]
});
```

Comment: on error occur here in both fiddle i can see input moves little up which I want to prevent

Comment: so in this case you can put css and put fixed position of error. so it will not be moved.

Comment: i have resolved this issue but new issue is css files are not adding in index.html in proper order. i have updated in app.json but when i open architect it reset the order